# Retrieving remote files based on data from table and whether they exist locally using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can anyone please advise me of the best way of doing this task, I don’t want the script written for me (I like learning) I just need a pointer in which would be the best way to approach the problem,

I download xml files for each of the products in my catalog they are titled (`ProdId.xml`)

I get a list of the product id’s from my SQL Server 2008 table products. And currently put them into Excel and put a wget statement before each file with the full path and username and password for my source of the files.

E.g.

```
wget website/xmlfiles/prodid.xml – username – password
```

And I do this for each and every file.

I would like to automate the process so daily extract all the product id’s check to see if the file already exists then if not go collect from the website.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into writing an [SQL Server Integration Services or SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) package to perform this for you. SSIS can be used for data extraction, transformation and loading.

There are a lot of tutorials online about SSIS. Here are a few:

[MS SQL Tips - SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/200/sql-server-integration-services-ssis/)

[SSIS Tutorial: SQL Server 2005 Integration Services Tutorial](http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssis_tutorial.htm)

[SSIS Tutorial: Creating a Simple ETL Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks bluefeet Ill check out the resorces

Answer (score 0):

Used this script in the end

```
DECLARE @Product_ID INT
DECLARE Product CURSOR
FOR SELECT Product_ID
FROM dbo.table

OPEN Product

declare @Paths varchar(128) ,
@FileName varchar(128),
@FileExtension varchar(128)

FETCH NEXT FROM Product
INTO    @Product_ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

select  @Paths = 'C:\Data\xmls\' ,
@FileExtension = '.xml',
@FileName = @Product_ID


declare @objFSys int
declare @i int
declare @File varchar(1000)

select @File = @Paths + @FileName + @FileExtension
exec sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @objFSys out
exec sp_OAMethod @objFSys, 'FileExists', @i out, @File
if @i = 1
print 'Allready There ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), @Product_ID)
else

PRINT 'Neet to get ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(36), @Product_ID) + '.xml From Source.'

FETCH NEXT FROM Product
INTO @Product_ID

exec sp_OADestroy @objFSys 
END

CLOSE Product
DEALLOCATE Product
```